# Angular 6 component inside the alertifyjs

Tags: angular6, alertifyjs

I want to use the alertifyjs with angular 6. And want to embed angular component into the alertifyjs body.

Example code:

```
import * as _alertify from 'alertifyjs';
_alertify.alert('Title' , '<app-custom-component></app-custom-component>');
```

or

```
_alertify.alert('My Title', '<dx-data-grid ...>...</dx-data-grid>');
```

[Example image with Devextreme datagrid](https://pasteboard.co/HKlPhG4.png)

How can I do embed the angular component into the alertifyjs? Or, can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass the whole component as body content. As per the alertifyjs Docs, it supports title and body content as string. So you can pass component.elementref.nativeElement.innerHTML.

**Template:**

```
<app-custom-component #customcomp></app-custom-component>
```

**Component:**

```
@ViewChild('customcomp') customcomp : ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit(){
   _alertify.alert('Title' , this.customcomp.nativeElement.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you, Apparently, I need an alternative to alertifyjs.

Comment: @kursatsonmez It accepts both String or DOMElement, `_alertify.alert('Title' , this.customcomp.nativeElement)` works too!